# What are "implicit triggers" in a Google Action package?

Tags: actions-on-google, api-ai

My Google Action was rejected. One of the reasons was:

> Your agent has too many implicit triggers in it's action package. Please limit the number of query patterns in your action package which do not include your invocation name to less than 10.

My `userSays` object includes around 30 phrases because I used API.AI's training system so that my assistant would understand any type of input from the user and extract the parameters needed. Is this what Google is referring to. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is likely the issue you are running into. API.AI is creating an action package for your project behind the scenes. If you want to learn more about it, take a look at the Actions SDK docs.

Comment: Thanks, Leon. I managed to be more selecting with my userSays phrases and that appears to have been the problem.